# Displaying formulas in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, mathml

I'm looking for the best way to display relatively simple mathematical formulas in ActionScript. So far the best solution that I found is the "MathML Parser written in ActionScript 3": http://www.sevenson.com.au/actionscript/mathml/
The author generously published the source code, and it's a good start, but it needs more work.

I also found http://www.fmath.info/ , but I don't see how it can be used with pure ActionScript (I'm not using Flex).

My question is: can you recommend a good AS3 library that would render MathML or a similar formula language as a Sprite?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Problem: Display mathematical formulas in ActionScript. What has been done: Tried http://www.sevenson.com.au/actionscript/mathml/ and http://www.fmath.info/ . Both are not complete solutions to the above problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best one I've seen: http://sharemath.com/

It covers a wide range of mathematical inputs. Most of it adjustable from XML I think as well. It's worth looking into even if you just want to get a base of what it might look to make it from scratch.

There is also something known as LaTeX that we use often: http://validi.fi/latex2flash/

Either way speaking from experience, it is a very tricky process doing this from scratch so having something to at least base it off of is a extremely useful.

LaTeX integration example taken from the link provided above:

```
package
{
  import flash.display.*;
  import flash.text.*;
  import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

  public class Test extends MovieClip
  {
    private var latexField : LatexField;
    private var inputField : TextField;

    public function Test()
    {
      inputField = new TextField();
      inputField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
      inputField.border = true;
      latexField = new LatexField();
      latexField.eqString = "\\sum_{i=0}^ni=1+2+3+4+\\ldots +n";
      latexField.x = 200;
      addChild(inputField);
      addChild(latexField);
      inputField.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpListener);
    }

    private function keyUpListener(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
      //ENTER
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        latexField.eqString = escape(TextField(e.target).text);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, but this is not what I'm looking for. As I hope should be clear from the question, I need some AS3 code (library, package, etc.) that would render a math formula to a Sprite in runtime.

Comment: That cannot be done without either downloading some library or building it yourself (as stated in my answer), we are not going to code this for you which is why I posted links to sources for you to base it off of. Also LaTeX integration I linked is a library you can download and use and does exactly what you are asking. Please review the answer more closely. This is speaking from professional work experience integrating this exact functionality you are asking for. Furthermore I'll post the code from the LaTeX integration, found directly on their site.

Comment: OK, I downloaded and installed LaTeX2Symbol.zxp. The example code that you posted causes "1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: LatexField." Any idea why?

Comment: You problem haven't imported the libraries.

Comment: Where are the libraries? BTW, I've been using Flash and AS for almost 10 years and I include many 3rd-party libraries in my code. The http://validi.fi/latex2flash/ solution seems to be some kind of Flash IDE extension, so that's why I thought it's not what I need. However, I'm open to suggestions and do appreciate your help.

Comment: This has to be used from the server. Download this zip file, it will show you how:

[LatexLoader](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12830922/LatexField-TestBed.zip)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46127/discussion-between-user1566515-and-bennett-yeates)